# How to sort and recover datetime

Tags: sorting, go, hyperledger, chaincode

I am sitting on a Go structure in which there is a date type among the variables. When applying an order to the structure using this date field, the date does not return, only the default value.
I'm using hyperledger fabric to store the values ​​and retrieve them.
The value stored in chaincode is this:

```
Chaincode invoke successful. result: status:200 payload:"{\"XXX\":1,\"YYY\":12 ,\"ZZZ\":92,\"DATE\":16/Nov/2020 17:50:04}"
```

Where the "DATE" argument I'm setting inside chaincode using time.NOW().UTC().Format(....)

I have the struct called N with the fields:

```
type N struct {
        Xxx int `json:"XXX"`
        Yyy int `json:"YYY"`
        Zzz float64 `json:"ZZZ"`
        Date time.Time `json:"DATE"`
}
```

I'm trying  recovery using the function GetHistoryForKey(args[0])

```
hist, err := APIstub.GetHistoryForKey(args[0])
          
    var listHist = make([]N, 0)
    for hist.HasNext() {
         resp, err := hist.Next()
         var node N
         err = json.Unmarshal(resp.Value, &node)
         listHist = append(listHist, node)
    }
        
    sort.Slice(listHist, func(i, j int) bool { return listHist[i].Date.Before(listHist[j].Date) })
        
        
    var buffer bytes.Buffer
    var jsonStr string
    for _, nodo := range listHist {
         jsonBytes, _ := json.Marshal(node)
         jsonStr = string(jsonBytes[:])
         buffer.WriteString(jsonStr)              
    }
        
    return buffer.String(), nil
```

But when I call this function to sort the history the DATE value came wrong, like this:

{"XXX":1,"YYY":12,"ZZZ":92,"DATE":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"}

If I call other function that recovery this specific key, the right value returns ok.

{"XXX":1,"YYY":12,"ZZZ":92,"DATE":16/Nov/2020 17:50:04}

What I'm doing wrong to no return values sorted?

I'm setting dates this way:

```
func set(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) (string, error) {
        if len(args) != 2 {
                return "", fmt.Errorf("Something error")
        }
        var currDate = time.Now().UTC().Format(("02/Jan/2006 15:04:05"))
        var ret = strings.Replace(args[1], "???", currDate, -1)
        err := stub.PutState(args[0], []byte(ret))
        if err != nil {
                return "", fmt.Errorf("something", args[0])
        }
        return retorno, nil
}
```

Invoking througth this code:

```
docker exec -it cli peer chaincode invoke -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C mychannel -n mychain -c '{"Args":["set","key1", "{\"XXX\":1,\"YYY\":80,\"ZZZ\":30.0,"\DATE\":???}"]}'
```

Comment: Can you add the declaration code of your `N` struct ?

Comment: Hi, I had declared, but no like code, sorry... I have corrected.

Comment: Any help or tip is welcome, since I’ve already spent a lot of time trying ;)

Comment: You're not checking the error from `json.Unmarshal`, which could be relevant. Have you confirmed the dates in the JSON input to this function are valid?

Comment: I believe that not checking is ok, because I get return other fields stored, less the date. I put more information on post how I call and what I pass to function.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by placing the entry date in the format 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z before inserting it in the blockchain.
When I search, the date is formatted correctly with the right values.